# What is another way to make the last div to extending to the max he can

Tags: html, css

In order to make the last div extend according to the height of the viewport,
I used:

```
body {
display: flex
}

."main-container"{     <---- the last div
flex:1                
}
```

Is there other way getting this result without using flexbox?

Here is my codepen:

```
https://codepen.io/hadassf/pen/rNJNBpB?editors=1100&fbclid=IwAR3a_hbrJPoeRWnseZlpkv2aBVOS9H1PxTpRqAK24jVper3wjrd5qXQlRpM
```

Answer (score 0):

I think since its the main container you give it a height of 100% i.e .main-container{ height: 100%;}, because the display:flex is just for telling your parent element (in this case your .main-container), how you want it's child elements to be distributed within it. I hope I got your question correct.

Comment: To be honest I didnt quiet catch what you are trying to convey, what is you suggestion? what can I do in order to get the same result?

Comment: Im saying give the div a height of 100%, it will always fix the height of the "remaining space".

Answer (score 0):

vh is for viewport height, you can give 100vh if you want to size within viewport height.